# Static images in drawRect or in reuse cell method?

Tags: iphone, performance, cell, reusability, drawrect

I was testing adding a static image in an reused cell vs drawing it in the cell with drawrect method. I tested both methods and it seems drawing the image every time the cell gets in display is faster then adding the image to an reused cell.

Anyone knows, how this is possible? i have two more static images, should i draw these in drawrect or add them to the reused cell?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a different cell identifier for cells with different images and only setting the static image once (at creation)?

Comment: yes, i am only using one cell identifier, because all my cells have the same image. And its set at the cell creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define "adding a static image".

Pretty much any way you are adding it, the image view you are using has drawRect called to display the image.

By doing your own cell-level draw rect work, you take away some layers of calls and also have everything drawing on one layer (the cell) instead of compositing cell layers with UIImageView layers.

Comment: By static i mean. Adding an image that doesn't change to all the cells.